# How to save file in the file system and its path in the database using Python?

Tags: python, django, database, base64

I want to save file to the file system, currently I am working with django and it provides a pretty neat way of doing this:

models.py

```
class Report(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'charts', blank=True, null=True)
    remarks = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

utils.py (this file is created by me):

```
import base64, uuid
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

def get_report_image(data):
    f, str_img = data.split(';base64, ')
    decoded_img =  base64.b64decode(str_img)
    img_name = str(uuid.uuid4())[:12] + '.png'
    data = ContentFile(decoded_img, name=img_name)
    return data
```

And to save this data to the data base I use django orm

```
Report.object.create(name="report name", remarks='Report Remarks', author=request.user.id, image=get_report_image(base64_encoded_image))
```

But I want to do the same thing without django

Sorry for any mistake I made in asking the question or explaining my problem, I am a beginner

Comment: What kind of tool(s) you are considering to use instead of `django`?

Comment: SQLAlchemy as the ORM, and PostgreSQL as the database